# Storing a lambda in a array got by switch statement, then use it

Tags: ruby, arrays, lambda, switch-statement

In my script (for Ruby >= 1.9)  below I defined a Table class, which responsability is to generate 2 to 10 addition or multiplication table (chosen with a parameter). Then I call table method from a new Table instance in order to print result in a file.

This is the script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Table

HEADER_LINE = "="*25
add_operation = lambda { |op1, op2| op1 + op2 }
mul_operation = lambda { |op1, op2| op1 * op2 }

def table(req_operation = :mul)

    operation, op_label =   case req_operation
                            when :add
                                [add_operation, "+"]
                            when :mul
                                [mul_operation, "*"]
                            else
                                raise "Unknown operation #{req_operation} !"
                            end


    (2..10).each do |op1|
        yield HEADER_LINE
        yield "Table de #{op1} (x#{op_label}y)"
        yield HEADER_LINE
        (1..10).each do |op2|
            yield line = "#{op1} #{op_label} #{op2} = #{operation.call(op1, op2)}"
        end
        yield HEADER_LINE
        yield
    end
end

end

File.open("MyFile", "w") do |file|
    Table.new.table do |line|
        file.write "#{line}\n"
    end
end
```

The parallel assignement on line 11 tries to set a lambda to operation and a string to op_label. Indeed, on line 26, I want to apply the lambda to op1 and op2 local variables.

But I get the following error :

```
./operation_table.rb:15:in `table': undefined local variable or method `mul_operation' for #<Table:0x00000000f1fc48> (NameError)
    from ./operation_table.rb:38:in `block in <main>'
    from ./operation_table.rb:37:in `open'
    from ./operation_table.rb:37:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way to correct it while keeping the parallel assignement ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_operation` and `mul_operation` are local variables, declared outside the function, and cannot be accessed by the function `table`.

You can declare it inside the table function, or store as class variables.

```
def table(...)
  add_operation = lambda { |op1, op2| op1 + op2 }
  mul_operation = lambda { |op1, op2| op1 * op2 }
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer : what code can I adapt if I want to store both lambdas as Class variables ? (Sorry for this beginner question)

Comment: Oh my god ! That is with @@, of course. I had already forgotten.

Comment: or class constants: `AddOperation = ...`

Comment: @tokland Thank you : I had forgotten this solution too. Ruby's philosophy "There is several ways to do it" leads to power :)

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE, yep. I'll suggest using class constants in this case, but it's up to you :)

Comment: @Dogbert Yes you're right : these values won't need to be changed later :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to resort to lambdas for such a simple thing as binary operations, define a hash `operator_symbols` containing a mapping `operator_string => operator_symbol` and use it this way:

```
operand1.send(operator_symbols[operator_string], operand2)
```

Comment: Thank you :) I did not know : looks like I need to explore Ruby API more ! (Especially Fixnum class)

Comment: Very interesting indeed : 3.send(:**, 2) # => 9